# Correct configuration of pcs and libvirt

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pacemaker

So I was able to configure PCS and libvirt to work properly together.  I can migrate VMs between my two nodes with no problems.  All was working well until I needed to place one of my nodes in a standby mode for maintenance.  It seems that my resource for the shared filesystem is being taken down before the VMs are able to completely migrate to the other node.

I have tried using ordering and configured an orderly boot up for everything, but when I put a node into standby mode, the resources on BOTH nodes shutdown and are then restarted on the non-standby node.  I have played around with the kind=Optional switch on the constraints, but have not gained any ground.

I know this must be an easy answer, but I can't find it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Terry

```
<cib crm_feature_set="3.0.10" validate-with="pacemaker-2.5" epoch="428" num_updates="0" admin_epoch="0" cib-last-written="Mon May 22 16:22:42 2017" update-origin="kvm01" update-client="crm_attribute" update-user="root" have-quorum="1" dc-uuid="2">
  <configuration>
    <crm_config>
      <cluster_property_set id="cib-bootstrap-options">
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-have-watchdog" name="have-watchdog" value="false"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-dc-version" name="dc-version" value="1.1.15-11.el7-e174ec8"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-infrastructure" name="cluster-infrastructure" value="corosync"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-name" name="cluster-name" value="kvm"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-stonith-enabled" name="stonith-enabled" value="true"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-no-quorum-policy" name="no-quorum-policy" value="freeze"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-last-lrm-refresh" name="last-lrm-refresh" value="1495482722"/>
      </cluster_property_set>
    </crm_config>
    <nodes>
      <node id="1" uname="kvm01">
        <instance_attributes id="nodes-1"/>
      </node>
      <node id="2" uname="kvm02">
        <instance_attributes id="nodes-2"/>
      </node>
    </nodes>
    <resources>
      <primitive class="stonith" id="kvm01_ilo" type="fence_ilo4_ssh">
        <instance_attributes id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-pcmk_host_list" name="pcmk_host_list" value="kvm01"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-ipaddr" name="ipaddr" value="10.0.1.40"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-login" name="login" value="Administrator"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-passwd" name="passwd" value="iloadmin"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-action" name="action" value="reboot"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-secure" name="secure" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-instance_attributes-delay" name="delay" value="15"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="kvm01_ilo-monitor-interval-60s" interval="60s" name="monitor"/>
        </operations>
        <meta_attributes id="kvm01_ilo-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="kvm01_ilo-meta_attributes-target-role" name="target-role" value="Stopped"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="stonith" id="kvm02_ilo" type="fence_ilo4_ssh">
        <instance_attributes id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-pcmk_host_list" name="pcmk_host_list" value="kvm02"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-ipaddr" name="ipaddr" value="10.0.1.41"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-login" name="login" value="Administrator"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-passwd" name="passwd" value="iloadmin"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-action" name="action" value="reboot"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-secure" name="secure" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-instance_attributes-delay" name="delay" value="15"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="kvm02_ilo-monitor-interval-60s" interval="60s" name="monitor"/>
        </operations>
        <meta_attributes id="kvm02_ilo-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="kvm02_ilo-meta_attributes-target-role" name="target-role" value="Stopped"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="ClusterIP" provider="heartbeat" type="IPaddr2">
        <instance_attributes id="ClusterIP-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ClusterIP-instance_attributes-ip" name="ip" value="10.0.1.10"/>
          <nvpair id="ClusterIP-instance_attributes-cidr_netmask" name="cidr_netmask" value="32"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="ClusterIP-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="20s"/>
          <op id="ClusterIP-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="20s"/>
          <op id="ClusterIP-monitor-interval-30s" interval="30s" name="monitor"/>
        </operations>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="BAK01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="BAK01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="BAK01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="BAK01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/bak01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="BAK01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="BAK01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="BAK01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="BAK01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="BAK01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="BAK01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="BAK01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="BAK01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="BAK01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="BAK01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="BAK01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="BAK01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="BAK01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="2048"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="CMS01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="CMS01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="CMS01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="CMS01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/cms01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="CMS01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="CMS01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="CMS01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="CMS01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="CMS01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="CMS01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="CMS01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="CMS01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="CMS01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="CMS01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="CMS01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="CMS01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="4"/>
          <nvpair id="CMS01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="32768"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="ELK01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="ELK01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/elk01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="ELK01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="ELK01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="ELK01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="ELK01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="ELK01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="4"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="32768"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="ELK02" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="ELK02-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK02-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK02-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/elk02.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK02-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK02-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="ELK02-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK02-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK02-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="ELK02-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK02-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK02-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="ELK02-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK02-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="ELK02-utilization">
          <nvpair id="ELK02-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="4"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK02-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="32768"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="ELK03" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="ELK03-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK03-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK03-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/elk03.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK03-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK03-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="ELK03-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="ELK03-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK03-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="ELK03-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK03-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK03-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="ELK03-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="ELK03-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="ELK03-utilization">
          <nvpair id="ELK03-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="4"/>
          <nvpair id="ELK03-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="32768"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="IPA01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="IPA01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="IPA01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/ipa01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="IPA01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="IPA01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="IPA01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="IPA01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="IPA01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="IPA01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="3072"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="IPA02" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="IPA02-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="IPA02-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA02-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/ipa02.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA02-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA02-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="IPA02-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="IPA02-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA02-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="IPA02-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA02-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA02-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="IPA02-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="IPA02-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="IPA02-utilization">
          <nvpair id="IPA02-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="IPA02-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="3072"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="PXY01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="PXY01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="PXY01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="PXY01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/pxy01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="PXY01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="PXY01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="PXY01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="PXY01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="PXY01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="PXY01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="PXY01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="PXY01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="PXY01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="PXY01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="PXY01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="PXY01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="PXY01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="2048"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="WIK01" provider="heartbeat" type="VirtualDomain">
        <instance_attributes id="WIK01-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="WIK01-instance_attributes-hypervisor" name="hypervisor" value="qemu:///system"/>
          <nvpair id="WIK01-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/shared/vms/qemu_configs/wik01.xml"/>
          <nvpair id="WIK01-instance_attributes-migration_transport" name="migration_transport" value="ssh"/>
          <nvpair id="WIK01-instance_attributes-migrate_options" name="migrate_options" value="--p2p --tunnelled"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="WIK01-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="WIK01-meta_attributes-allow-migrate" name="allow-migrate" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="WIK01-meta_attributes-priority" name="priority" value="100"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="WIK01-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="WIK01-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="WIK01-monitor-interval-10" interval="10" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
          <op id="WIK01-migrate_from-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_from" timeout="120s"/>
          <op id="WIK01-migrate_to-interval-0" interval="0" name="migrate_to" timeout="120s"/>
        </operations>
        <utilization id="WIK01-utilization">
          <nvpair id="WIK01-utilization-cpu" name="cpu" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="WIK01-utilization-hv_memory" name="hv_memory" value="2048"/>
        </utilization>
      </primitive>
      <clone id="dlm-clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="dlm" provider="pacemaker" type="controld">
          <instance_attributes id="dlm-instance_attributes"/>
          <operations>
            <op id="dlm-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="90"/>
            <op id="dlm-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="100"/>
            <op id="dlm-monitor-interval-30s" interval="30s" name="monitor" on-fail="fence"/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="dlm-clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="dlm-clone-meta_attributes-interleave" name="interleave" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="dlm-clone-meta_attributes-ordered" name="ordered" value="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </clone>
      <clone id="clvmd-clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="clvmd" provider="heartbeat" type="clvm">
          <instance_attributes id="clvmd-instance_attributes"/>
          <operations>
            <op id="clvmd-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="90"/>
            <op id="clvmd-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="90"/>
            <op id="clvmd-monitor-interval-30s" interval="30s" name="monitor" on-fail="fence"/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="clvmd-clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="clvmd-clone-meta_attributes-interleave" name="interleave" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="clvmd-clone-meta_attributes-ordered" name="ordered" value="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </clone>
      <clone id="clusterfs_vms-clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="clusterfs_vms" provider="heartbeat" type="Filesystem">
          <instance_attributes id="clusterfs_vms-instance_attributes">
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_vms-instance_attributes-device" name="device" value="/dev/cluster_vg_vms/cluster_lv_vms"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_vms-instance_attributes-directory" name="directory" value="/shared/vms"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_vms-instance_attributes-fstype" name="fstype" value="gfs2"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_vms-instance_attributes-options" name="options" value="noatime"/>
          </instance_attributes>
          <operations>
            <op id="clusterfs_vms-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_vms-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_vms-monitor-interval-10s" interval="10s" name="monitor" on-fail="fence"/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="clusterfs_vms-clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="clusterfs_vms-clone-meta_attributes-interleave" name="interleave" value="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </clone>
      <clone id="clusterfs_logs-clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="clusterfs_logs" provider="heartbeat" type="Filesystem">
          <instance_attributes id="clusterfs_logs-instance_attributes">
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_logs-instance_attributes-device" name="device" value="/dev/cluster_vg_logs/cluster_lv_logs"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_logs-instance_attributes-directory" name="directory" value="/shared/logs"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_logs-instance_attributes-fstype" name="fstype" value="gfs2"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_logs-instance_attributes-options" name="options" value="noatime"/>
          </instance_attributes>
          <operations>
            <op id="clusterfs_logs-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_logs-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_logs-monitor-interval-10s" interval="10s" name="monitor" on-fail="fence"/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="clusterfs_logs-clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="clusterfs_logs-clone-meta_attributes-interleave" name="interleave" value="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </clone>
      <clone id="clusterfs_backups-clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="clusterfs_backups" provider="heartbeat" type="Filesystem">
          <instance_attributes id="clusterfs_backups-instance_attributes">
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_backups-instance_attributes-device" name="device" value="/dev/cluster_vg_backups/cluster_lv_backups"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_backups-instance_attributes-directory" name="directory" value="/shared/backups"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_backups-instance_attributes-fstype" name="fstype" value="gfs2"/>
            <nvpair id="clusterfs_backups-instance_attributes-options" name="options" value="noatime"/>
          </instance_attributes>
          <operations>
            <op id="clusterfs_backups-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_backups-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="60"/>
            <op id="clusterfs_backups-monitor-interval-10s" interval="10s" name="monitor" on-fail="fence"/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="clusterfs_backups-clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="clusterfs_backups-clone-meta_attributes-interleave" name="interleave" value="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </clone>
    </resources>
    <constraints>
      <rsc_location id="location-IPA01-kvm01-INFINITY" node="kvm01" rsc="IPA01" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="location-IPA02-kvm02-INFINITY" node="kvm02" rsc="IPA02" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="location-ELK01-kvm01-INFINITY" node="kvm01" rsc="ELK01" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="location-ELK02-kvm02-INFINITY" node="kvm02" rsc="ELK02" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="location-ELK03-kvm01-INFINITY" node="kvm01" rsc="ELK03" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="cli-prefer-PXY01" node="kvm02" role="Started" rsc="PXY01" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_location id="cli-prefer-WIK01" node="kvm02" role="Started" rsc="WIK01" score="INFINITY"/>
      <rsc_order first="dlm-clone" first-action="start" id="order-dlm-clone-clvmd-clone-mandatory" then="clvmd-clone" then-action="start"/>
      <rsc_order first="clvmd-clone" first-action="stop" id="order-clvmd-clone-dlm-clone-mandatory" then="dlm-clone" then-action="stop"/>
      <rsc_colocation id="colocation-clvmd-clone-dlm-clone-INFINITY" rsc="clvmd-clone" score="INFINITY" with-rsc="dlm-clone"/>
      <rsc_order first="clvmd-clone" first-action="start" id="order-clvmd-clone-clusterfs_vms-clone-mandatory" then="clusterfs_vms-clone" then-action="start"/>
      <rsc_order first="clusterfs_vms-clone" first-action="stop" id="order-clusterfs_vms-clone-clvmd-clone-mandatory" then="clvmd-clone" then-action="stop"/>
      <rsc_colocation id="colocation-clusterfs_vms-clone-clvmd-clone-INFINITY" rsc="clusterfs_vms-clone" score="INFINITY" with-rsc="clvmd-clone"/>
      <rsc_order first="clusterfs_vms-clone" first-action="start" id="order-clusterfs_vms-clone-clusterfs_logs-clone-mandatory" then="clusterfs_logs-clone" then-action="start"/>
      <rsc_order first="clusterfs_logs-clone" first-action="stop" id="order-clusterfs_logs-clone-clusterfs_vms-clone-mandatory" then="clusterfs_vms-clone" then-action="stop"/>
      <rsc_colocation id="colocation-clusterfs_logs-clone-clvmd-clone-INFINITY" rsc="clusterfs_logs-clone" score="INFINITY" with-rsc="clvmd-clone"/>
      <rsc_order first="clusterfs_logs-clone" first-action="start" id="order-clusterfs_logs-clone-clusterfs_backups-clone-mandatory" then="clusterfs_backups-clone" then-action="start"/>
      <rsc_order first="clusterfs_backups-clone" first-action="stop" id="order-clusterfs_backups-clone-clusterfs_logs-clone-mandatory" then="clusterfs_logs-clone" then-action="stop"/>
      <rsc_colocation id="colocation-clusterfs_backups-clone-clvmd-clone-INFINITY" rsc="clusterfs_backups-clone" score="INFINITY" with-rsc="clvmd-clone"/>
    </constraints>
    <fencing-topology>
      <fencing-level devices="kvm01_ilo" id="fl-kvm01-1" index="1" target="kvm01"/>
      <fencing-level devices="kvm02_ilo" id="fl-kvm02-1" index="1" target="kvm02"/>
    </fencing-topology>
  </configuration>
</cib>
```

Comment: More information would be helpful. Could you please share your current cib?

Comment: My company policy does not allow me to post it.  Is there anything from my cib that I can look for that would help you in helping me?

Comment: That is very unfortunate. You cannot "sanitize" the configuration and post it? Perhaps just the constraints and VirtualDomain resource definitions would be sufficient. I am mostly curious if you have the allow-migrate=true meta option for the VirtualDomain resources and if your constraints are sane.

Comment: How do you ensure migration is complete? What do you do if migration fails? What if it fails to converge after a very long time? It's been a while, but I don't remember seeing anything like that in pacemaker's configuration. My point being - if you're doing VMs, it is better to use a VM dedicated HA system that takes care of these things out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I do have allow-migrate=true.  I can migrate a VM from one node to the other with no issue.  The issue is as I put a node into standby.  It seems that the filesystem clone is being shutdown before the VMs are able to gracefully migrate to the other node.  Let me see what I can do about sanitizing the file and getting it past my supervisor.

Comment: I added updated the original post with my cib.  There is actually another VM on there called ELK04, but I had to remove its info to fit into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your configuration, I can probably only point you to the sections of documentation that I think might be relevant...

Take a look into the `interleave` option for your cloned resources in the Pacemaker documentation. It sounds like this might be what you're after.

Copied from http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.0/html/Pacemaker_Explained/ch10s02s02.html :

> interleave: Changes the behavior of ordering constraints (between
>   clones/masters) so that copies of the first clone can start or stop as
>   soon as the copy on the same node of the second clone has started or
>   stopped (rather than waiting until every instance of the second clone
>   has started or stopped). Allowed values: false, true. The default
>   value is false.